# Extract list of parameters from generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a generic type

```
type A<T,U,V,W> = ...
```

and I want to extend it as

```
type B<T,U,V,W> = A<T,U,V,W> & { ... }
```

No problems so far, but let's say `T,U,V,W` are actually very long definitions with extends and defaults.

Is it possible to do it in a DRY way? Such as

```
type GenericArgs<T> = ...?? // custom or builtin utility type

type ArgsA = GenericArgs<A> // <T,U,V,W>
type B<ArgsA> = A<ArgsA> & { ... }
```

Comment: I guess... make aliases for the constraints and defaults?

Comment: `A` comes from a library. Aliasing it on my end would make less sense than just copy-pasting.